# how to create set of item with different template in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

i have a set of item under clarisonic catalog.I want to create the same set of items in another place.for example.I want to create same set of items under amazon with different template.

First i am getting all child items under clarisonic catalog and getting the name of those items.I am creating new items under Amazon with the names which i got it earlier with different template.[image]

I want to create same set of items under amazon[all items under clarisonic catalog].

```
public void EntryPath(Item item)
        {
            List<string> ObjSiteNames = getMultiListValues(item, "Select Site");
            GetChildrenSelectedItem(item, ObjSiteNames);
            RecursiveItemCreation(item);
        }


        public List<string> getMultiListValues(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, string FieldID)
        {

            Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multiselect = item.Fields[FieldID];
            return multiselect.GetItems().Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
        }

        public void GetChildrenSelectedItem(Item getChildredItem, List<string> sitesnmaes)
        {
            string defaultSitePath = "/sitecore/content/Administration/Sites";

             masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
            templateItem = masterDb.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/User Defined/SC-DW Data/Generic/Widgets/NavigationItem");
            foreach (string str in sitesnmaes)
            {
                StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                strBuilder.Append(defaultSitePath).Append("/").Append(str);
                itemDesPath = masterDb.GetItem(strBuilder.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void RecursiveItemCreation(Item Getchilds)
        {
            foreach (Item i in Getchilds.GetChildren())
            {
                i.Template = masterDb.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/User Defined/SC-DW Data/Generic/Widgets/NavigationItem").
                if ((i.HasChildren))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    itemDesPath.Add(i.Name, templateItem);
                    foreach (Item ItemDes in itemDesPath.Axes.GetDescendants())
                    {
                        if (ItemDes.Name == i.Name)
                        {
                            ItemDes.Editing.BeginEdit();
                            ItemDes.Fields["Datasource"].Value = i.Paths.Path;
                            ItemDes.Editing.EndEdit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Think you may need to re-phrase this question; I find it unclear exactly what it is you are asking.

Comment: Yeah, I also have no clue what you're asking...

Comment: Perhaps you want to look into [Branch Templates](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2012/10/Page-Editor-Secrets-1-Complex-Content-Creation.aspx)

Comment: I think they're asking for the functionality of branch templates but with the added ability to set the template of the resulting items at the point of creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to copy the whole tree below `Clarisonic Catalog` item to the `Amazon` node. The only difference is that the created items should use different template (`/sitecore/templates/User Defined/SC-DW Data/Generic/Widgets/NavigationItem`).

Code below should do the job. I haven't tested it but I'm sure you can solve all the problems you'll encounter.

```cs
public void CopyTreeStructure(Item source, Item target)
{
    // find the new template you want to use
    TemplateItem newTemplate = new TemplateItem(source.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/templates/User Defined/SC-DW Data/Generic/Widgets/NavigationItem"));

    foreach (Item child in source.Children)
    {
        // create the copy of original item using new template
        Item copiedItem = CreateItemUsingNewTemplate(child, target, newTemplate);
        // repeat for all descendants recursively
        CopyTreeStructure(child, copiedItem);
    }
}

private Item CreateItemUsingNewTemplate(Item source, Item targetParent, TemplateItem templateToUse)
{
    // create item
    Item copiedItem = targetParent.Add(source.Name, templateToUse);

    // pre-read all fields
    source.Fields.ReadAll();

    using (new EditContext(copiedItem))
    {
        // update all the fields of new item
        foreach (Field field in source.Fields)
        {
            copiedItem[field.Name] = source[field.Value];
        }
    }

    // return copied item so we can copy it's descendants
    return copiedItem;
}
```